# Extract an email address from the body of an email

Tags: vba, email, outlook-2010

I'm trying to automate a response to emails we receive from our webhost.

The emails contain an address to send the response.

How do I extract an email address from the body of an email, and insert it into the **TO** of a new email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to deal with the message body.

To set the TO field in Outlook you can use [the corresponding property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860378.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or use the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865320.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) collection. The following line of code uses the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866951.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to add 'Dan Wilson' as a To recipient:

```
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Set myRecipient = mailItem.Recipients.Add("Dan Wilson")
```

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you I will look into this! :)